# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error in restapi response

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Yesterday I have created my first rest api.

Here is my code

```
package RestClient;

//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/RestClient")
public class Restwebclient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Webservice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient</param-value>
</init-param>   
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

When I run, Apache server starts fine in eclipse. But when I open the url on local host where I'm expecting my data not coming. Its shows error like in below screen shot.

https://prnt.sc/gjatoq

Same error with these urls as well

```
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/RestClient
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Restwebclient
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Restwebclient/Test
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test
```

I have tried every single thing, switched the location as well and selected "use Tomcat Installation" option as well. I'm really kind of stuck.

Everything seems to be running okay except the output data on local host url.

Is there anyone who could share with me anything further to make it work ?

Comment: the eclipse project, is it named "Webservice"?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher..yes, Its Webservice ..!!

Comment: check the context root. it is under "Web Project Settings" in the project's settings

Comment: is there an "index.html" in the web root folder? (`WebContent`)

Comment: by the way, if you're using `@Path` annotation, you don't need servlet mapping in web.xml

Comment: @SharonBenAsher..Please check this...here is the hierarchy 
 https://pnt.sc/gjb1bv and I cant see any index.html file.

Comment: check the context root. write up an index.html with "Hello World" and put it under `WebContent`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher..here is the output http://prntscr.com/gjb2x2 but I want my output in xml and should come from code where I have mentioned in return statement. Why its not coming ?

Comment: You sohuld call http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test     and make sure that you send a header that accepts xml   `Accept: text/xml`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher..on this localhost:8080/Webservice/Test...am still getting same error...And what do you mean by this "make sure that you send a header that accepts xml Accept: text/xml" ? Could you please give one example...?

Comment: try localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/RestClient

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, Its still the same error ..!! :)

Comment: try to change the url mapping to this  `<url-pattern>/Test/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: btw, the class `Restwebclient` is actually the server side of the rest communication...

Comment: btw, by convention, package names in java start with lower case letter...

Comment: @SharonBenAsher...Its showing now xml. Thanks a alot man putting effort with me. But could you please tell me, How this hierarchy working step by step. I mean First webservice then Test an then RestClient ? I mean What makes them to come into only in this order only ? and what was specific using /Test/* instead of /Test ?

Comment: First the context root via Eclipse setting - this will affect all http requests: browser requests (remember index.html) and api ones.     then come the url mapping in web.xml. this will affect all api calls.   then come the class annotation that will affect all methods in that particular class.  In rest, a class should represent one resource and the `@Path` should reflect that resource name (for example `@Path ("/Users")`) and other resources will be handled by other classes, all of them come under the same context root and url mapping

Comment: the url mapping tells Tomcat how to route incoming requests to possibly different servlets. without the star (`<url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>`) it maps the entire incoming url, so only `localhost:8080/Webservice/Test` would be routed to the servlet but then the servlet would not pass the request to the `Restwebclient` class.

Comment: the mapping with star (`<url-pattern>/Test/*</url-pattern>`)  tells tomcat to route all requests where the url starts with the specified text. hence the url `localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/RestClient` would be routed to the jersey servlet and it would pass the request to your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)` it means that the reponse will include an HTTP header named `Content-Type` and its value will be `text/xml`

However, the request from the client must be able to accept this response.  The client must send an `Accept` HTTP header with the same value (can also be `application/xml`)  otherwise the web server may decide not to send the response or the client may decide to throw the response away.

Chrome (or any other browser) is probably not the best tool to test rest api calls (or api in general).  Not only because of HTTP headers, but also to be able to use HTTP methods other than GET.  You can search chrome web store for mods that allow modification to http headers, or use a proper http client tool

I use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-wizard).  it has a wealth of features, including total control of the HTTP request contents.

Comment: In the case of a wrong MediaType, the response should be something like 405 and not 404, right? But I would also recommend a Rest-client like Postman.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, well what ever you said make sense to me I guess. But like you said client should also have ability to accept xml response. How can I make this ? Any suggestion...because its my very first development